# User existence check is not working in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I found this site which was describing a very simple user authentication for LINQ to SQL as at [codesamplez.com](http://codesamplez.com/database/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-tutorial).

My data in the Database looks like this

```
| id  | name | password |
+-----+------+----------+
| 1   | tic  | test     |
| 2   | tac  | test     |
| 3   | toe  | test     |
```

For some strange reason the data doesnt validate as I expect, when I call

```
 bool b  = IsValidUser("tic" , "test");
```

this returns `FALSE`,
But any time I pass the same Username and password combination

```
 bool b  = IsValidUser("tic" , "tic");
```

or

```
 bool b  = IsValidUser("a" , "a");
```

or

```
 bool b  = IsValidUser("b" , "b");
```

it returns `true`!

below is the code which is basically identical to the referenced page.

```
public bool IsValidUser(string userName, string passWord)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var users = from u in db.Users
                      where u.name == userName
                      && u.password == passWord
                      select u;

    return Enumerable.Count(users) > 0;
}
```

**Update:** 
The User class:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Users")]
public partial class User
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _password;

    public User()
    {
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id != value))
            {
                this._id = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_name", DbType="NChar(10)")]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._name != value))
            {
                this._name = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_password", DbType="NChar(10)")]
    public string password
    {
        get
        {
            return this._password;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._password != value))
            {
                this._password = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it should work to me; how did you create your data context and entity classes?  Did you use sqlmetal.exe against your database?  I ask, because the only way I can imagine your code failing is if the `[Column]` attribute on your password property is mapped to the wrong column (i.e. to the username column).

Comment: side note: I would wrap  your DataClasses1DataContext in a 'using' statement since that object is disposable.

Comment: no I just use the default from VSExpress when I created the ADO.NET database

Comment: @IEnumerable, well, for kicks, can you post your entity class for `User`?

Comment: @Kirk Woll - I just added the User partial class that has the Mapping - which was all basicly generated code from VS

Comment: have you manually inspected the users object in the debugger to see if what you expect is the actual? I just get this feeling that the source of the data is somehow not from the db you think it's using. Ex: ASP.NET using local db and making modifications to the db would often be overwritten on publish with an older version of the db. Just a thought since you haven't specified what env you're dev'ing for..

Comment: Thanks everyone, all very helpful info now. It was my own mistake here, the Database didnt have the data I expected in it. I had 2 database servers and the new data hadnt replicated over to the development server.

Comment: Why not `return Queryable.Count(users) > 0;`

Comment: @IEnumerable, I know it will feel weird, but please post your above comment as the "answer" and then accept it as the correct answer.  (the SO way)

Comment: ok thanks, im still learning this site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, all very helpful info now. It was my own mistake here, the Database didnt have the data I expected in it. I had 2 database servers and the new data hadnt replicated over to the development server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your issue is, but this should get you more info:

```
public bool IsValidUser(string userName, string passWord)
{

    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    db.Log = System.IO.StringWriter(New StringBuilder());

    var users = from u in db.Users
                where u.name == userName
                && u.password == passWord
                select u;

    int userCount = users.Count();
    bool isSuccess = userCount > 0;

    return isSuccess;   //Breakpoint here, check the contents of db.Log
}
```

If you put a break point on the return then you can examine `userCount` and `isSuccess`.  You can also check `db.Log` to see what query was run.

If this does not solve your problem then please update your question with the value of these three variables at the return.

**Update**  I just saw your update.  Sounds like you are referencing the wrong `IsValidUser` method.  I would go to where you are calling it, right click on `IsValidUser` and select "Go To Definition" to verify the correct method is being called.  Also, verify that your using the latest build.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public bool IsValidUser(string userName, string passWord)
{
    using (var db = ...)
    {
        ...
        return users.Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just made this same lecture to Leon Newswanger (deleted below).  Do we have to go over this again? :)  (i.e.  there is no chance whatsoever this answer will help the OP resolve his question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public bool IsValidUser(string userName, string passWord)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    return db.Users.Any(u => u.name == userName && u.password == passWord);
}
```

Comment: For the **3rd** time, the OP's use of particular extension methods cannot conceivably produce different results.

Comment: Just what difference do you think `.Any(...)` vs `.Count() > 0` will possibly produce?

Comment: @ Kirk Woll, Both are Same, But rather than finding the users and checking for count, you can use ANY, It is looks good interms of redability and speed.

Comment: of **course** it does.  But if your answer will not help the OP solve his problem, it should be a *comment*.  Otherwise, you pollute the answers with noise and even worse, run the risk of your "answer" being upvoted by the unwary, and annihilating the OP's hopes of getting his question seen by the hordes of "unanswered questions" viewers.

Comment: @Kirk Woll, Do you think, you are expecting me the give exact answer (IEnumerable Said, Thanks everyone, all very helpful info now. It was my own mistake here, the Database didnt have the data I expected in it. I had 2 database servers and the new data hadnt replicated over to the development server.). I suggested instead query and count use ANY.. it is straight forward. I didn't understand wht your trying to educate me here.

Comment: No idea what your point is.  My point is that your answer is merely a style guide.  Answers on SO should be trying to help the OP solve his problem.  The answerability of said question is moot.